# What functionality does the "g?" command provide in vim

Tags: vim, rot13

As a beginner programmer I've been practicing vim on vimgolf recently and saw that the command "g?" was used effectively to switch many lines of 'Ivm' to become 'Vim'. I understand that this shifts each alphabetical letter 13 times to the right but do not understand how this would prove useful except in unique circumstances like these.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: I use it for learning English. I tend to collect new vocab/expr/idioms etc. in a file. I "hide" the meaning of that word with g?, because I want to learn by inferring the meaning by looking at the examples.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `g?` command (type `:help g?` for brief documentation) implements the [`rot13`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rot13) algorithm, which rotates each letter 13 places forward or backward in the alphabet.

I'm not sure how commonly it's used today, but on Usenet it used to be a common way to encode spoilers. For example, if I'm writing a post that gives away the ending of something that not everyone has seen, I might use `rot13` to weakly encrypt part of the article. It's enough to make it impossible to read accidentally (unless you've had a lot of practice), but easy to read if you're using a newsreader that has a built-in `rot13` function -- as most of them do.

For example:

> Pretend this is a spoiler. Filter with rot13 to read it.

would become

> Cergraq guvf vf n fcbvyre. Svygre jvgu ebg13 gb ernq vg.

If I don't want to read the spoiler, I can ignore it. If I do want to read it, I can decrypt it easily enough.

Comment: How to use vim's builtin rot13 feature. Ex1:  1. `v` to enter visual mode 2. select your text 3. `g?` to apply rot13 to this text. Ex2 - do the entire buffer: `ggVGg?` (translation: `gg` go to the start, `V` linewise visual selection mode, `G` go to the end, `g?` apply rot13).

Comment: To elaborate, on @TrevorBoydSmith's comment `g?` is a verb so it can be applied to `w`ords or `p`aragraphs or whatever. This functionality isn't limited to visual mode.

Comment: thanks, I got here because I was wondering why would I want that and not, say, base64? or ever want rot13 as more than a novelty? But that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 13):

I have been using Vim since 4 years and learned about that command very early on but, even if I knew perfectly well what ROT13 was, I *never* found a use for `g?`.

Until a couple of weeks ago when I needed to add a bunch of `<li>` with unique IDs to a `<ul>` in an HTML prototype…

The starting point:

```
<ul>
    <li id="lorem">foo</li>
    <li id="ipsum">foo</li>
</ul>
```

After duplicating the two `<li>`:

```
<ul>
    <li id="lorem">foo</li>
    <li id="ipsum">foo</li>
    <li id="lorem">foo</li>
    <li id="ipsum">foo</li>
</ul>
```

After `g?i"` on the two new `<li>`'s `id`s:

```
<ul>
    <li id="lorem">foo</li>
    <li id="ipsum">foo</li>
    <li id="yberz">foo</li>
    <li id="vcfhz">foo</li>
</ul>
```

There! I found a practical use for `g?` in actual "programming"! Celebration!!!

Answer (score 0):

It can prove useful on the case where you want to quickly hide some part of text that you typed in a visible vim buffer from onlookers.

For example some piece of password or token which you put in your code (but only do this temporarily, when you must).

Perhaps you want to invite a team-mate to look at some of your code, or you work in a place where people use to walk behind your back all the time so you can just rot13 the string and it is useless to them (at least in a glance).
It probably works best against non technical passerby's or for short exposure period.

Keep in mind it does not rotate numbers and for security purposes it was even better if it could take a rotation size.

It can also become useful when you solve a CTF that has a rot13 challenge...