# How to AUTOMATICALLY transform processed files in vim, as they are read/written?

Tags: vim

Imagine for a moment that my boss is insane.  He wants all our file encrypted, so he insists that they all be ROT-13'd on disk.

I still want to edit them like normal, however, so I'd like vim to ROT-13 the file after reading it, and before presenting it to me for editing.  And when I save the file, I want to ROT-13 it before writing it to disk.

Is there a way to do that?  While looking for similar situations, I found [textutil.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1432) which claims to convert `.rtf` or `.doc` files to plain text, and then convert them back when you save... but it's overkill for my purposes.

(For those who are curious, my actual use case is that I want to reformat the spacing and layout the way I like it, prior to editing source code, and then reformat it the boss's way whenever I save.  I have a custom build of clang that does this reformatting, but I don't know how to get vim to run it.)

Someone mentioned the "g?" command.  That's not the point of this question.  I know how to transform my text; what I don't know is how to do it without having to manually execute a command.  The point is, I want vim to *automatically* transform a file *prior* to me seeing even one line of it, and then *automatically* transform it back when I save it... probably based on its filename extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What functionality does the "g?" command provide in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224741/what-functionality-does-the-g-command-provide-in-vim)

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_obscure_text_instantaneously

Comment: How about just doing it the boss's way?

Comment: You would actually get useful answers if you actually posted a useful question. What exactly is "boss's way" and what exactly is "the way I like it"? It's likely autocommands can do what you want, but it may also be there's a much more simpler answer depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Amadan, I'm looking for a general solution that will automatically transform files in whatever way I choose prior to them appearing in vim, and automatically transform files in some other way prior to them being written back to disk.  So let's say there's a file named foo.rot13 that only contains "ebg guvegrra".  I want to know how to configure vim so that when I type "vim foo.rot13", I am greeted with the words "rot thirteen", not "ebg guvegrra".  It should be completely transparent.

Comment: It would actually be a very useful feature. Another use case could be editing JSON as YAML. There is a plugin for that, https://github.com/fourjay/vim-yamsong, but it'd be nice to generalise the concept and support it natively.

Answer (score 1):

All right, here's how keep all your files rot13d. You must have a very weird boss.

```
augroup rot13
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePre,BufWritePost * normal ggg?G``
augroup END
```

`BufWritePre` should prepare it for writing to disk; `BufWritePost` and `BufReadPost` should undo those modifications.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, this is very close to what I'm looking for.  One tweak is to use '*.rot13' rather than just '*'... otherwise it becomes immediately impossible to edit the .vimrc file.  Though I'll probably have to ask this question again just to get the incorrect "The question may already have an answer here" tag off.

Comment: You said "He wants all our file encrypted". You can still edit `.vimrc` by bypassing loading `.vimrc` using `vim -u NONE .vimrc`. Or, as you said, replace `*` with another pattern to match buffers more precisely.